# Context free grammar with or conditionals

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to find a CFG for the language:

$$L = \{a^nb^mc^o: n = m \text{ or } m \neq o\}$$

The `or` is tripping me up in the language. So far I have something like:

$$\begin{align}S &\to A | B \\
A &\to aAb | \epsilon \\
B &\to aB | C | E \\
C &\to bCc | bD \\
D &\to bD | \epsilon \\
E &\to bEc | Fc \\
F &\to Fc | \epsilon
\end{align}$$

In order of lines above:

- split problem into two subproblems
- add equal a and b or end (follows $n = m$)
- add any number of a
- add equal b and c or add b
- then add b or end (follows $m > o$)
- add equal b and c or add c
- then add c or end (follows $m < o$)

My thought process is if $m > o$ or $m < o$, then $m \neq o$, thus both conditions are satisfied, but this is incorrect for the first part of the `or` conditional: $n = m$. Note I can't have strings like $abcc$ which satisfies both conditions because a $c$ cannot be added if $n = m$ in line $A \to aAb | \epsilon$.

A more declarative language for the CFG I have is:

$$L = \{a^nb^mc^o : (n = m \text{ when } o = 0) \text{ or } m \neq o\}$$

Which is not the language the question asks me of. I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: or (in logic) is inclusive: $n=m \text{ or } m≠o$ is true if both $n = m$ and $m \ne o$. So you could regard the language as the union of two independent languages, which precisely corresponds to the meaning of a disjunctive rule in the CFG.

Comment: @rici ah, of course! I can just add another producer for $c$ after $A$. $A \to aAb | G | \epsilon, G \to cG | \epsilon$ satisfies all conditions if it's inclusive or. Thanks!